# boost or openMP for multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, boost, openmp

i have to parallize some code and a fried of mine suggested using boost for it. Right now i have a look into openMP and i am wondering what you think is better for that task.

Comment: you could also think of using raw pthreads. I think it strongly depends on your code, as usual. some googleing will help you out in finding out the differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is up to you

I personally went with boost threads, because it found OpenMP to be very lacking once I needed more advanced features

for simple loops, OpenMP is fine, for more complex things, actual threads may be needed.

Comment: up to now i really just need simple loops, and together with visual studio 2008 it is awesomely easy: added openmp language support in project settings, included <omp.h> added this two lines in front of my for loop (#pragma omp parallel shared(foo, bar) private(i) and #pragma omp for schedule(guided) ) and i am done...